# Грамотность и замечания

Tags: общие-вопросы

Когда я вижу безграмотно написанные сообщения на форумах, блогах и "в контакте", я стараюсь всегда указывать авторам сего безобразия на их ошибки. Это же касается и безграмотных ценников в магазинах (только недавно сказала сотрудникам супермаркета, написавшим на ценнике "кабачёк", а о "гриб фруктах" я вообще молчу). Часто из-за этого  нарываюсь на грубости или обиды. Но и пройти мимо безграмотности не могу, хоть и не скажу, что моя собственная грамотность стопроцентна.
Как вы считаете, правильно ли я делаю, или все же нужно не обращать внимания?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Совершенно согласна с Ларf, под каждым словом подписываюсь. Замечания можно делать очень тактично, никого не обижая.
В продуктовых магазинах чаще всего встречается ошибка в слове "сгущённое". Пишут с одной Н. В хозтоварах слово ЛИНОЛЕУМ иногда коверкают. В отделении полиции на двери табличка "Комната для задержаНых".
 Часто я фотографирую объявления с ошибками, а на уроках прошу исправить их. Если объявление висит на улице и до него можно легко дотянуться, явные ошибки исправляю аккуратно сама, пока никто не видит. Думаю, что авторы не обижаются.

Исправлять ошибки в речи гораздо труднее. Очень многих замечание раздражает, ибо задето самолюбие говорящего. И чем старше человек, тем он в этом отношении сложнее. Я позволяю себе исправлять речь своих учеников до выхода их из школы, а потом делаю это редко и очень осторожно. Близких людей тоже не дёргаю, иначе общение стало бы натянутым, менее тёплым и сердечным. Выход есть:нужно просто ещё раз употребить "неправильное" выражение, но только в исправленном виде, как бы между прочим. А вот совсем не обращать внимание на ошибки, я думаю, нельзя.

Comment: Прекрасный ответ! Согласна!  
Для смеха - такая история. Как-то увидела ценник "Грильяж из семян подсолнуха", в котором три слова из четырех были написаны неправильно. Догадайтесь, где не было ошибки? В слове "грильяж"!   
"Грильяж ис семьян подсолнухи"  
Видимо, на "трудном" слове человек дал себе труд задуматься...

Comment: Благодарю Вас! С ценником и в самом деле случай забавный.
 А у меня один мальчик в 5 классе написал в сочинении слово "серно". Только из контекста я поняла, что оно означает. Оказалось, ВСЁ РАВНО.

Comment: Сирано - такой  вариант был у меня. А ещё из запомнившихся - колбаса с солями (салями)

Comment: Позавчера был у меня диалог "ВКонтакте". Пишет мужик, предлагает товар и добавляет, что "доставка за наш ЩЕТ". Я отвечаю, что не знаю такого слова: "Это что, от слова "щетка"?". А он мне еще поясняет: "Это от слова "рахунок". Говорю, что и от слова "рахунок" не знаю))))

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, все зависит от ситуации. Важно чувствовать, как примет твое замечание собеседник. Если на лице написано 2 класса образования и ты чувствуешь, что тебя не поймут, зачем портить настроение. Человек и так обделенный, как говорят, Богом обиженный. И замечание все равно ничему его не научит. В магазинах, в которых я часто делаю покупки, я всегда здороваюсь со всеми продавцами, замечания, если нужно, делаю тоном необидным, как бы в шутку.  Никаких грубостей в ответ не слышала никогда. Если человек мне незнаком, могу сказать так: "Можно, я Вам замечание сделаю?"или "Можно, я ошибку исправлю?" /Все доброжелательно и с улыбкой/ - ДАльше по ситуации. Но конфликтов никогда не было. 
В интернете замечания не делаю. Ошибки в устной речи могу исправить только у близких знакомых. 
В общем. все индивидуально и по ситуации. 
Считаю, что поправлять нужно, но обижать при этом своим высокомерием - нельзя.

Comment: Видимо, у Вас просто город культурный. А у нас... Я тоже всегда стараюсь говорить предельно деликатно, но не все это понимают.

Comment: Не культурный. Просто маленький провинциальный. И говорю далеко не всем. Ну не буду же я поправлять молодежь, которая с трёх пополудни до трех ночи кричит под окнами и чаще матом... Её утихомирить не удается даже с помощью милиции, не то что научить грамотности, делая замечания.

Comment: Кстати, приглашаю посмотреть мою коллекцию фотографий из серии "нарочно не придумаешь" — там как раз в основном языковые ляпы. Все снято мной, никаких перепостов))) Просто, для поднятия настроения:
http://vk.com/id151920834#/album151920834_147133227

Answer (score 3):

Fuchoin Kazuki, я считаю, что Вы поступаете правильно. Я поступаю так же. К счастью,на грубости или обиды не нарывалась. Ценники
на "суфофрукты", "заворное пирожное", "Изюменку" (булку) после моих замечаний были добросовестно заменены:)

Comment: А вот сколько я не билась с "греями", "грей фруктами" и т.д. (грейпфрутами), все без толку.)))

Answer (score 2):

На этом сайте в основном общаются интеллигентные люди, как правило, с высшим филологическим образованием. Странно было бы увидеть другие ответы на поставленный вопрос. У меня филологического образования нет. Но русский язык для меня родной, и учила его не по словарям. Разговариваю я так, как разговаривают люди вокруг меня. Возможно, это не всегда совпадает со словарями, но меня понимают. И, честно говоря, меня раздражают грамма-наци, которые постоянно делают замечания за не правильно сказанные слова. Особенно когда это не знакомые мне люди. 
Уважаемые филологи, ответьте на вопрос. Что первичнее: живой язык, на котором говорят носители этого языка, или словари?
Я тоже негативно отношусь к публичным вывескам, написанным с ошибками, но мне лично нравится очень высказывание Чехова: 
"Хорошее воспитание не в том, что ты не прольешь соуса на скатерть, а в том, что ты не заметишь, если это сделает кто-нибудь другой."

Comment: > Что первичнее: живой язык, на котором говорят носители этого языка, или словари?

Первичен живой язык. Но язык не любого носителя :-). Здесь речь даже не о Пушкине, а о людях, использующих язык умело и уместно.

> меня раздражают грамма-наци, которые постоянно [...]

Почему *постоянно*? Вы делаете так много (повторяющихся) ошибок? 

p.s. Приведённое высказывание Чехова ещё более ханжески-нравоучительное, чем некоторые мысли Толстого. [Пушкин и Чехов несовместимы](http://www.akhmatova.org/articles/losev1.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Я, например, очень редко делаю замечания о безграмотной речи. Не делаю этого по одной единственной причине: я не русский и по опыту знаю, что попытка указать на любую безграмотность "русскаго" автоматом приводит собеседника в ярость, причем, что характерно, уровень образованности человека играет оч. маленькую роль.

Comment: Когда делает ошибки человек, для которого русский язык не является родным — это одно, а когда русский коверкает родной язык — совершенно другое.

Answer (score 0):

В основном я исправляю тех людей, которым это может пригодиться, например одиннадцатиклассников, которым надо сдавать ЕГЭ или ЦТ (централизованное тестирование в Беларуси). Бывает, исправляю людей, которые следят за своей речью и стараются говорить грамотно. Такие обычно воспринимают мои поправки с благодарностью. Конечно, иные раздражаются, когда их исправляют, ведь они так уверенны в своих знаниях, что даже не подозревают, что допускают кучу ошибок. Но мне с моими благими намерениями давно стелется дорога сами знаете куда.

[[@yupaz](/users/1370/yupaz)](/users/1370/yupaz), у меня нет высшего филологического образования. Русский язык - мое хобби, поэтому и сижу на этом форуме. То, что вы называете "живым языком" есть штука непостоянная. Людей много, кто-то говорит так, кто-то - иначе, а словари фиксируют то, как говорит большинство. Авторы не придумывают эти нормы (хотя бывают и очень подозрительные случаи, например перЕгнутый и полшагА).

Хотя недавние реформы опровергают то, что нормы могут создаваться только большинством. С "кофе" среднего рода ещё можно согласиться, так как это очень распространенная ошибка, но никакое большинство никогда не говорило "йогУрт", это вообще странное и не соответствующее русскому языку ударение, так как звук "йо" обычно ударный.

Язык постоянно развивается, и нормы будут постоянно меняться. Таков закон. Но отслеживать его развитие - дело авторов словарей. Они должны всё вовремя фиксировать.

Comment: Честно говоря, я вообще не поняла, откуда они этот "йогУрт" взяли. До этой реформы я ни разу ни от кого не слышала такого ударения. По-моему, так говорил какой-нибудь начальник тех чинуш, что принимали этот закон. Решили прогнуться))))))

Answer (score 0):

Валентин, извините за "поправку": *стелиться* - глагол первого спряжения (*брить, стелить* - исключения), следовательно, окончание **-ет** ("стелется дорога сами знаете куда). Исправляю потому, что случай не самый лёгкий, а Вы человек грамотный. 
По существу вопроса: я исправляю очень редко, в магазинах никогда. Наверно, у меня не получается делать это тактично.  И авторитетно (мне часто просто не верят).

Comment: Подзабыл это правило. Спасибо, что исправили.